# How to I call a non-static method from a child class that uses variables from parent without creating an instance

Tags: python-2.7, class

I am trying to call a method from a child class that is using variables from its parent without creating an instance. Is that possible in Python?

Using this as an example:

```
class F(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


instance = F(2, 1, None)

class T(F):

    def foo(self):
        self.c = self.a - self.b


T.foo()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You have to instanciate `T` to access instance attributes of its parent `F`.

When using `T` to access static `T` stuff, you only have access to static `F` stuffs too.

In your example, the `F` you instanciate has nothing to do with the `F` that would be the parent of `T` if you instanciated it.

It's not the same instance and has not the same reference. As a counter example, if your example worked, what would happen if you instanciate `F` multiple times? How would you choose between the multiple `F` to read for your static `T`?

Comment: The code I use is just an example, but I have a long piece of code, where creating such a function makes sense. In that code I create the instance through another child function before. What I would like to do is call a method that uses variables which are defined in the parent function and it doesn't make any sense to create another instance just to call that method. There are other ways of solving this I am aware, but I was just wondering if there was a decoration in python that could make a method do this, as the method is not @staticmethod as it takes uses variables from the parent.

Comment: The example you posted is non-sensical (see my comment). Python (or any properly scoped language) could resolve names/references in this context. If you have a more sensical example please provide it. But I'm pretty sure that it will not be possible. Asking a static class to use instance attributes of its parent, is like asking an orphan to call his parents, not possible…

Comment: Ok thank you. I guess that I have to place the method in the class where I call the instance from. I was just wondering if there was a way, but I see you rpoint.